# Change colour of contacts (Nokia 6)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, contacts, color, nokia-6

Is it possible to change the colour of the contacts? It is getting confusing with my text conversations all colour coded but contacts completely random...

Comment: You could invite them all for a game of paintball. </kidding> What contacts you're asking for: in the standard contacts app, in some messenger, …?

Comment: He may be asking about default color settings for each contacts added to phone.( Google contact app, bcz, nokia 6 is stock android )  After addition of a new contact, the app saves contact with First letter and a background color as default avatar. May be he's asking how to change that color.

Comment: Yeah that's the one, default contacts. It's strange because logging into google mail and they might have a different colour lol But yeah basically I have my conversations colour coded but when i create a new contact it picks a random colour I don't seem to be able to change. So is that the answer, it's based on the first letter? Edit - nvm, realised you didn't mean the colour was based on the letter...

Answer (score 0):

i haven't been able to change contact colours, but you can change the text message conversation colours. go into the conversation of the person you want to change the colour of, tap the more button and go to people & options, there should be a little palette next to the name of the person you want to change